# after failed attempt to install HAM for android studio, getting compile error in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have failed to install HAM software for the android studio. It gave a error alert saying vt-x should be enabled. But after that the compilation in android studio started givng a problem. The log from compiling is as follows:

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       D:\AndroidNewSetup\newsdk\build-tools\20.0.0\dx.bat --dex --no-optimize --output D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\dex\uat\debug D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\classes\uat\debug D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-5eb35d3ffd9a9241c5b094f0bf2272ac102305b0.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\EnsightenAspect-Client-c8e967b342d1ed907a85146c22c1fb8be74f2433.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\javax.inject-1-da2f0738adb03c6d7edd76e41d1c341bfc32030d.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\support-annotations-21.0.3-78331f49d930f12aa340f7cb9f23708c2bad8eb4.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\aopalliance-1.0-aa4aa7470dc4178bb3c786a5c336dd5518520899.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\android-smart-image-view-1.0.0-3f1ea61d0ee30f673a03597ad6d151350d877fc9.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\EnsightenAspect-0c89813864cf5228e71ab0992ea20552843222a0.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-2bc8723337adeffd34c94f4de218552df28deeec.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-cc7feb5dab8c208fa18f0b72bc86718477b6c552.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-d92dfbd7894b4566f637ffdedcd17312a35d80bd.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\httpmime-4.2.2-a486694bd26f1f95caf71b195185c1171df3b736.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\okhttp-urlconnection-2.2.0-17434d41750130fb7a4b6dc273c3e95377bbed16.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\okio-1.2.0-0c4081afbfc924379b972e850a455fe5ebb638cd.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\hirondelle-date4j-1.5.1-5a4bf541d99a6706c0a093bda96e5b076bdc2554.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\asm-3.1-8a362ea13c794af182ec588c9e5868fde5204e7e.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\xtify-android-sdk-2.4.2.2-9313c20d9d8ca869a6a34b12e477e8fdcbb41bf3.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\aspectjrt-1.7.1-a0b57a15d86207c447c84505efce3ce7d3031e11.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\roboguice-2.0-b73b1a88a94ab94eca8e5caad1549622712693a5.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\library-2.4.0-8e25eb19e4bdf565c5de6c35bb00caa2654b6065.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\retrofit-1.9.0-9b58d633d8e0ad1d457224b3619cd2ca06b8bb0e.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\picasso-2.5.0-27d18700e30709beab3bf875b81479c27a2bd491.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\internal_impl-21.0.3-18a6b4416c6dc1e43935e71b39071ab0482e92ec.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\gson-2.3.1-6c88f17fa6d5a3b8942bb4245a097a60b3d262c7.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\httpcore-4.2.2-886ac947a5c5003642aa877216512384df57acd1.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\cglib-2.2.1-v20090111-cf5171d2fc33e4092d97cd713e88c5ca3b159830.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\adobeMobileLibrary-c359345f5dc94bdd1e62bb32dc935762d5070369.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\logback-android-core-1.0.10-2-29ad0ea5d6c5fcabc9bc70d10076020e9f0429c8.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-e0d4d51c86e7d888f139081c827ce4fa1bdbd636.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\okhttp-2.2.0-e262ac91a665a3752ca6f299663d494da20bff70.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-64695536aede25d57b459b712ed3d598d535c245.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\guice-3.0-no_aop-0693294c2e5b2223f2fa8418ccb4b4b5330b0a9e.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\commons-lang3-3.0-0d2df215bb7551976979d7b3b623bc3bcecd8bf4.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\Ensighten-a40d62135b82979886bcc3c12b3e8b789caba835.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\crittercism-android-agent-5.2.0-569ca7cb7df98e21077c7af24f46407ea9795d85.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-4d2f48619934796186efcbd76a556741c9fb762e.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\sdk-android-3.3.0-nodeps-b3ade3c586f0c6a4f4f2867e9c04c0e45d1be50a.jar D:\Mari\Marriott Code Base\may12\android-dev\app\build\intermediates\pre-dexed\uat\debug\classes-528bff2aec271ac5853d199fcafabf609606699c.jar
>   Error Code:
>       2
>   Output:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
```

### com.android.dex.DexException: Cannot merge new index 66168 into a non-jumbo instruction!

Please help me with this problem. Not able to compile the android project because of this.

Comment: careful you aren't displaying sensitive information here.